# i18n using database

Tags: database, internationalization

I have to design a database which will allow me store data in multiple languages. I came up with something like this.

```
create table lang ( id primary key, lang_code )
create table data (id primary key)
create table i18n_data (id primary key, i18n_text ,data_id references data, lang_id references lang)
```

Is creating a table with only one column/primary key is an overkill for my requirement? Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your solution is a quite nice one, I am solving such problems the same way. And I wouldn't fear to create a table only with a primary key (although you might find a few attributes which are belonging to this table).

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head I see two similar options:

Having just two tables `lang` and `i18n_data` and an **indexed field** in `i18n_data` that you use with the language to index the translation.

Another option could be to use a **composed primary key** on the `i18n_data` table that has the reference to `lang` and the `data` identifier.